# Data-title/data-original-title attributes and accessibility

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility

I have been searching for information about the attributes data-title and data-original-title. My issue is that Twitter Bootstrap converts the title-attribute into a data-original-title and I am not sure that this is what I want. What about screen readers for instance? Do they treat the data-title as a title, or do they ignore it? If I use one of those data-attributes, do I have to add a title-attribute as well?

Comment: data-* is for arbitrary additional attributes.  You should never replace a REAL attribute with one.   That said, data-title is NOT title from a semantic point of view.  Screen readers will do NOTHING with data-* attributes, unless they support the js/etc that invokes them to actually do something.  The title attribute is where the helpful messages will display as always.   Now, what Bootstrap is doing with them, I don't know.

Comment: @briansol the `title` attribute is not reliably announced by assistive technology either.

Answer (score 2):

The [custom `data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) are defined for HTML5. They are "intended to store custom data private to the page or application".

The spec says:

> These attributes are not intended for use by software that is independent of the site that uses the attributes.

So other tools (like screen readers) should not make use of them.

If something is a `title`, you should not use a `data-*` attribute (like `data-title`) in the first place, as the spec says "[…] for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements"; use `title`.