# Same information in multiple different formats, but only have it considered once

Tags: html, media-queries, semantic-markup

I have a booking form. I want it to respond to different devices. On a large desktop, there's loads of room, so I want to display a date and time like so:

> Saturday 15th September 2017 @ 1:30pm

On tablets, there's less space, so it needs to appear as:

> Sat 15th Sep 2017 @ 1:30pm

On mobile, there is even less space, so I simply want to show:

> 15/09/17 @ 1:30pm

This is easy to achieve by just hiding and showing some elements with media queries. Each user gets a format that best suits their device.

My concern is that, obviously, the same info is now in the markup 3 times, in 3 different formats. Is there some way to tell browsers / search engines / screen readers etc. that this is duplicate markup, and that the duplicates can be ignored?

Comment: Your question is primarily opinion based, but nevertheless - read this: http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_dates

Comment: I don’t see how this is opinion-based. It asks for a way to convey this in the markup -- and there are ways to do so. It might be a duplicate, but can’t find it right now. I voted to reopen.

Comment: I also don't think this is *primarily* opinion-based, voting to reopen. If it's a dup, then find it and close it properly.

Comment: FYI, that's a Friday and not a Saturday.

Comment: Also, if CSS is involved (as it would seem since you're hiding and showing elements), please tag your question [css].

Comment: @Alon Eitan: Where does that describe how to display dates in various formats responsively? I only see a description of how to use the time element with microdata to display a date in a single format.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as HTML doesn't support swapping content on-the-fly using media queries, I don't think there's a way to achieve this within the markup itself.

One way to achieve this using CSS is by making use of *generated* content in conjunction with custom data attributes to swap the date formats:

```css
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  time[data-mediumtime][data-shorttime] {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  time[data-mediumtime][data-shorttime]::before {
    content: attr(data-mediumtime);
    font-size: medium;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  time[data-mediumtime][data-shorttime]::before {
    content: attr(data-shorttime);
  }
}
```

```html
<time datetime="2017-09-15 13:30"
      data-mediumtime="Fri 15th Sep 2017 @ 1:30pm"
      data-shorttime="15/09/17 @ 1:30pm">Friday 15th September 2017 @ 1:30pm</time>
```

The reason I suggest custom data attributes is because, if [unor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631604/data-title-data-original-title-attributes-and-accessibility/25653783#25653783) and I read the spec correctly, custom data attributes should be ignored by crawlers and AT, meaning they should only see two things: the text content (i.e. the long date format), and the machine-readable `datetime` attribute (which is what they *ought* to be interested in to begin with). Here's the relevant text from the [living spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes):

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data, state, annotations, and similar, private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.
>
> These attributes are not intended for use by software that is not known to the administrators of the site that uses the attributes. For generic extensions that are to be used by multiple independent tools, either this specification should be extended to provide the feature explicitly, or a technology like microdata should be used (with a standardized vocabulary).

The only disadvantage of using generated content is that the generated content cannot be highlighted and copied, but this probably won't be an issue on tablets and mobile devices, and in windowed desktop environments it is still possible in all major browsers to copy the actual content regardless of what is actually being displayed — it just won't be highlighted when it's being hidden.

You can also just manipulate the content directly using JavaScript using `window.matchMedia()` with a listener, but besides requiring scripting to be enabled, I think that's entirely too much work just to swap date formats (which for that matter are largely cosmetic and so are well within the realm of CSS anyway) whilst avoiding duplicate content.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like an interesting approach!
It sounds like there's no specific way of specifically marking up duplicate content, but this could be a good way around it.
From what I can see, the browser support on something like this looks pretty good too, so I'll give it a go - thanks for your help!